# Start long running process and check output before process has terminated

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have an issue where I want to start a long running process from inside a running Java process and get the initial output before the long running process has terminated.

I.e. run java -jar myapp.jar which has unit tests and starts a long running process of an application installed on the same machine which will run until all my tests has completed.

In a normal case I would just use ProcessBuilder and do something like:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new
                ProcessBuilder("ls");
        Process p = pb.start();
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

How can I do similarly and start a long running process that doesn't terminate for several minutes or until I terminate it yet get the output? Any working solution is fine, it doesn't have to be with the ProcessBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to test with Mockito framework? There you can add @Before tests, wich runs before your output terminated. http://site.mockito.org Here you can read all abaout it!

Comment: That's a good idea to run it in the @Before block but I don't see how I can get the initial output from when the command line application is started.